# Optimize App Script to Copy Values based on a Condition

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've created the below function which copies formulas I have in cells K2:M2 to column B:D only if column A contains the word "Copy".

However, the performance is very slow looping through each cell to determine if the cell in column A contains "Copy".  How can I optimize this loop function?

```
function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var Sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var copy = Sheet1.getRange('K2:M2')
    
    for (var i=1; i<=1000; i = i + 1)
    if (Sheet1.getRange(i,1,1,1).getValue() == 'Copy'){
    copy.copyTo(Sheet1.getRange(i,2,1,3),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### copying forumulas

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rg = sh.getRange("K2:M2");
  var cs = rg.getFormulas();
  var vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var fs = sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),3).getFormulas();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
      if(r[0] == "Copy") {
        fs[i][0] = cs[0][0];
        fs[i][1] = cs[0][1];
        fs[i][2] = cs[0][2];
      }
    })
  sh.getRange(1,2,fs.length,3).setFormulas(fs);
}
```

Comment: This function copies the exact formula in range K2:M2 to every cell.  How can I get the output to be dependent on the row we are pasting to?  For example if cell K2 has the formula "=A2", if I copy to cell B14 I need the formula to show "=A14".